# Using JavaScript to properly sign a string using HmacSHA256

Tags: javascript, sign, postman, houndify

In the Houndify API Docs for Authentication, you have the following block of content:

---

#### An Example of Authenticating a Request

Let's assume we have the following information:

```
UserID: ae06fcd3-6447-4356-afaa-813aa4f2ba41
    RequestID: 70aa7c25-c74f-48be-8ca8-cbf73627c05f
    Timestamp: 1418068667   
    ClientID: KFvH6Rpy3tUimL-pCUFpPg==
    ClientKey: KgMLuq-k1oCUv5bzTlKAJf_mGo0T07jTogbi6apcqLa114CCPH3rlK4c0RktY30xLEQ49MZ-C2bMyFOVQO4PyA==
```

1. Concatenate the UserID string, RequestID string, and TimeStamp string in the following format: `{user_id};{request_id}{timestamp}`
2. With the values from the example, the expected output would be in this case: `ae06fcd3-6447-4356-afaa-813aa4f2ba41;70aa7c25-c74f-48be-8ca8-cbf73627c05f1418068667`
3. Sign the message with the decoded ClientKey. The result is a 32-byte binary string (which we can’t represent visually). After base-64 encoding, however, the signature is: `myWdEfHJ7AV8OP23v8pCH1PILL_gxH4uDOAXMi06akk=`
4. The client then generates two authentication headers *Hound-Request-Authentication* and *Hound-Client-Authentication*.
5. The Hound-Request-Authentication header is composed by concatenating the UserID and RequestID in the following format: `{user-id};{request-id}`. Continuing the example above, the value for this header would be:
   Hound-Request-Authentication: `ae06fcd3-6447-4356-afaa-813aa4f2ba41;70aa7c25-c74f-48be-8ca8-cbf73627c05f`
6. The Hound-Client-Authentication header is composed by concatening the ClientID, the TimeStamp string and the signature in the following format: `{client-id};{timestamp};{signature}`. Continuing the example above, the value for this header would be: `Hound-Client-Authentication: KFvH6Rpy3tUimL-pCUFpPg==;1418068667;myWdEfHJ7AV8OP23v8pCH1PILL_gxH4uDOAXMi06akk=`

---

For Number 3, it says "Sign the message with the decoded ClientKey". The "message" and "ClientKey" are two distinct strings.

My question(s): How do you sign one string with another string i.e. what exactly does that mean? And how would you do that in JavaScript?

```
var message = 'my_message';
var key = 'signing_key';

//??what next??
```

I'm trying to figure all this out so I can create a pre-request script in Postman to do a proper HmacSHA256 hash.

Comment: Apparently you have to sign in to view the api docs of Houndify.

Comment: @A1rPun Sorry, didn't know that. I'll post the relevant block instead of the link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation, if you're using one of their SDKs, it will automatically authenticate your requests:

> SDKs already handle authentication for you. You just have to provide
>   the SDK with the Client ID and Client Key that was generated for your
>   client when it was created. If you are not using an SDK, use the code
>   example to the right to generate your own HTTP headers to authenticate
>   your request.

However, if you want to do it manually, I believe you need to compute the [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) value of the string they describe in the link in your question and then send it base64 encoded as part of the `Hound-Client-Authentication` header in your requests. They provide an [example for node.js](https://www.houndify.com/docs/code-examples):

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var crypto = require('crypto');

function generateAuthHeaders (clientId, clientKey, userId, requestId) {

    if (!clientId || !clientKey) {
        throw new Error('Must provide a Client ID and a Client Key');
    }

    // Generate a unique UserId and RequestId.
    userId      = userId || uuid.v1();

    // keep track of this requestId, you will need it for the RequestInfo Object
    requestId   = requestId || uuid.v1();

    var requestData = userId + ';' + requestId;

    // keep track of this timestamp, you will need it for the RequestInfo Object
    var timestamp   = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),  

        unescapeBase64Url = function (key) {
            return key.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        },

        escapeBase64Url = function (key) {
            return key.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
        },

        signKey = function (clientKey, message) {
            var key = new Buffer(unescapeBase64Url(clientKey), 'base64');
            var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(message).digest('base64');
            return escapeBase64Url(hash);

        },

        encodedData = signKey(clientKey, requestData + timestamp),
        headers = {
            'Hound-Request-Authentication': requestData,
            'Hound-Client-Authentication': clientId + ';' + timestamp + ';' + encodedData
        };

    return headers;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying to create a Postman pre-request script to basically do what you have posted. I just needed to get my head around the concepts. This will help.

Answer (score 4):

So basically, signing [in this specific case] simply means to create a hash of the string using a hash algorithm in addition to a *key*, as opposed to a *keyless* hash [like MD5]. For example:

```
var message = 'my_message';
var key = 'signing_key';
var hashed_message = hash_func(message, key);
```

where hash_func is a hashing algorithm like HmacSHA256 (the hashing algorithm in question).

The reason I was trying to figure this out was to test authentication for the Houndify API using Postman. Fortunately, Postman has a nice feature called *pre-request scripts* [complete with hashing algorithms] that helps if you need to pre-generate values that need to be sent along with your request.

After much fiddling around, I managed to create a pre-request script that properly authenticates to this API (see code below).

```
var unescapeBase64Url = function (key) {
            return key.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        },

        escapeBase64Url = function (key) {
            return key.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
        },
        guid = function() {
    function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
        s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
    };

var client_id_str = environment["client-id"];
var client_key_str = environment["client-key"];
var user_id_str = environment["user-id"];
var request_id_str = guid();
var timestamp_str = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

var client_key_dec_str = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(unescapeBase64Url(client_key_str));

var message_str = user_id_str+";"+request_id_str+timestamp_str;
var signature_hash_obj = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message_str, client_key_dec_str);
var signature_str = signature_hash_obj.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

var hound_request_str = user_id_str+";"+request_id_str;
var hound_client_str = client_id_str+";"+timestamp_str+";"+escapeBase64Url(signature_str);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("hound-request-authentication", hound_request_str);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("hound-client-authentication", hound_client_str);
```

Note that you are going to have to create environment variables in Postman for *client-id*, *client-key*, and *user-id*, as well as for the header variables *hound-request-authentication* and *hound-client-authentication* to hold the final values that will be referenced when defining headers.

Hope it helps.